# Change attributes of a DOM element when it appears

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to change the attribute of a DOM element as it is created? I have an input (has an ID) that is created by a plugin. I need to change the placeholder of that input when it appears.

i.e.

```
$("#token-input_sample").live("attr","placeholder","place");
```

Code above doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

`on()` should be used to bind events to elements that exist now, or in the future. To manipulate properties or attributes of elements, you should use the [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) function:

```
$('#token-input_sample').prop('placeholder', 'place');
```

Comment: Yes I do understand. But where do I bind the "on" function if it or its parents) doesn't exist yet?

Comment: You have to update the property of the element when it gets created in the DOM.

Comment: It is created at an indefinite time. That's why I was thinking of adding live. Not sure how that would work

Comment: How can it be created at an indefinite time? It must be created either by an AJAX call, or timeout or by a user action, no? You must know where the code is to create the element in the DOM, so why not just set its property then...

Comment: ok, cards on the table. I am using a plugin called TokenInput http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/. What it does to the input (text) is it hides it and creates a new input box with a different id. But it doesn't have a callback onload, nor does it have an initialize function. So I was wondering if there was a way to add the placeholder to the newly created input, without tinkering with the plugin. (which makes it indefinite)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#token-input_sample").attr("placeholder", "Type an ID").blur();

$("#token-input_sample").attr("placeholder", "Type an ID");
```

this [link](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#placeholder) may also be helpful for you

Comment: Hmm, the Dom element doesn't exist yet when the page is loaded so this won't work